# How to rename keys ("PK_") and constraints ("DF_") automatically upon renaming table and/or column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, constraints, primary-key, rename

As you know, when we set a PK and/or constraint, a key/constrains name will be automatically created for us (`PK_...`, `DF_...`). But whenever I rename a column name and/or table name, those keys and constraints aren't automatically renamed accordingly.

Is there any setting in SQL that allow it to do it automatically?

Comment: I would **never** leave those system-generated names in place - I would recommend to always **explicitly specifying** your own constraint names. And with that, whenever you rename a table and / or column, it's your task to also rename the constraint(s) - often by dropping and re-creating them.

Answer (score 2):

**AFAIK** there is no setting. You will have to use `sp_rename` to rename the constraints after you rename the column name and/or table name.

Related Reading: http://davidbrycehoward.com/archive/2011/01/naming-and-renaming-database-constraints/